# Jenkins and Slack (Jenkins Slack app cannot be used in a script)

Tags: jenkins, slack

We want to post messages from Jenkins builds in 2 scenarios:

- Post build Step and
- From a python script

Unfortunately, the Jenkins CI app made by Slack ONLY works from Jenkins:
https://my.slack.com/services/new/jenkins-ci
So I can't use that app's credentials in a random python script.

And my own token cannot be used by the Jenkins Plugin, since it ONLY wants the integration token of the Jenkins CI app.

So this is forcing me to use 2 Jenkins CI apps: One from https://my.slack.com/services/new/jenkins-ci to work with the Jenkins Slack Plugin, and my own custom app just to get the token to use in jenkins scripts.

Is there a way to simply use a single Jenkins Slack app for both the Jenkins Plugin AND random scripts?

Comment: I'm able to use `slackSend` function from Jenkins Pipelines, but it is not portable into scripts tho. So you might need to investigate in running few Groovy logics to manages the Slack message depending on the Python output.

Comment: FYI, With Pipeline allowig to code in Groovy, you can modify Jenkins itself at runtime of a job; That mean pipelines has full access to the Jenkins unlilke the GUI.